# Let org-timestamp-up/down work on non-timestamp

Tags: org-mode, time-date

So in org-mode, shift-up and shift-down works on timestamps. Is there a way to let it work on arbitrary dates in the text that is not a timestamp? For example if I write

```
The date is 2019-01-01.
```

Would it be possible to use shift-up/down on the date there to adjust it?

Comment: No - `S-<up>` is bound to `org-shiftup` which, depending on the context, can call a number of different commands. If it is in a timestamp, it calls `org-timestamp-up` which calls `org-timestamp-change` which checks that it is in a timestamp with `org-at-timestamp-p`. If that returns nil, then `org-timestamp-change` bails out with an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a '<' before and a '>' after the date so org identifies it as a date
now you can go up and down via shift.
In Addition you can press `C-.` to open a the time stamp dialog.